# Family tree structure in c++

Tags: c++

I want to make a program that gets the information of a family including their names, SSN etc. I'm facing with two problems, firstly, what is the best data structure for this purpose,secondly, how should i get the information from the user, i mean when I'm getting info of father,i should determine his children, here is the problem.
how to connect his children to himself?

Comment: What information do you want to manage? What did you try? Show your C++ code!

Comment: Can you post your requirement point wise and also the code which you've written so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd create a few different parallel arrays.
You're going to need to find out the algorithms for search through the arrays.
You're going to need to find out how to match them up together using the same index once the search finds a match.  The index will probably be needed to be returned by reference to make things easier.
How to connect the children to the father maybe harder... 
I don't know much about Binary Trees, we never talked about those in class.  But that maybe the answer you're looking for.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  It's Christmas and it's 3AM lol.  Good luck.